# Can't get any items except for 3?

Tags: python

Hey guys i'm completing my text based game in python. Im able to move between rooms and can pick up only 3 items from my list(from only rooms mystinc depths, darkened crypt, and shadowy den) but if i continue to add items to my inventory i get the invalid entry not sure where the problem is.

```
def intro():
    # print the intro to the game
    print('In the depths of the Umbra vaults, you, a lone adventurer, will set out to confront the Shadow lord, a dark',
          '\n',
          'entity threatening the world with eternal night. You must go through each chamber to find items that will',
          '\n',
          'help you defeat the villain.')


def show_instructions():
    # print main menu and commands
    print('\n')
    print('You need to find the Shadow villain hiding in the chambers.')
    print('Move between chambers by using directions by typing go: North, South, East, and West.')
    print('Along the way you must pick up all 6 items to defeat the villain.')
    print('***To add an item to you inventory, type: get "item name"')
    print('***To exit game type: exit')
    print('Good luck and dont get caught')
    print('\n')


def moving_rooms(current_room, player_move, rooms):
    current_room = rooms[current_room][player_move]
    return current_room


def get_item(current_room, rooms, items_collected):
    items_collected.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']

def main():
    rooms = {
        'Twilight Foyer': {'East': 'Mystic Depths', },
        'Mystic Depths': {'North': 'Darkened Crypt', 'South': 'Whispering Hollow', 'East': 'Glowing Cavern',
                          'West': 'Twilight Foyer', 'item': 'Chalice'},
        'Darkened Crypt': {'East': 'Shadowy Den', 'South': 'Mystic Depths', 'item': 'Key'},
        'Whispering Hollow': {'East': 'Enigmatic Vault', 'North': 'Mystic Depths', 'item': 'Shadow cloak'},
        'Shadowy Den': {'West': 'Darkened Crypt', 'item': 'Dagger'},
        'Glowing Cavern': {'North': 'Enigma Hall', 'West': 'Mystic Depths', 'item': 'Glowing orb'},
        'Enigma Hall': {'South': 'Glowing Cavern', 'item': 'Radiant crest'},
        'Enigmatic Vault': {'item': 'Villain'}
    }
    # list for players stored inventory
    items_collected = []
    # start with current room
    current_room = 'Twilight Foyer'

    intro()  # tells game to show intro to game
    show_instructions()  # shows the player the instructions of the game

    while True:
        # if player wins game
        if current_room == 'Enigmatic Vault':
            if len(items_collected) == 6:
                print('Congratulations, you have collected all items and defeated the villain')
                print('Thanks for playing!')
                break
            # if player loses game
            else:
                print('You have encountered the shadow lord but you did not collect all 6 items to defeat him,'
                      'he has turned the whole world to eternal night and has defeated you')
                print('Thanks for playing!')
                break

        print("You are in the ", current_room)

        if not items_collected:
            print("You don't have any items.")
        else:
            print('You have:', ', '.join(items_collected))

        if current_room != 'Enigmatic Vault' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            print('You found the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        print('-----')
        player_move = input('Enter your move: ').title().split()

        if len(player_move) >= 2 and player_move[1] in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = moving_rooms(current_room, player_move[1], rooms)

        elif len(player_move[0]) == 3 and player_move[0] == 'Get' and ' '.join(player_move[1:]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            print('You picked up the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('-----')
            get_item(current_room, rooms, items_collected)

        elif player_move == ['Exit']:
            print('You are exiting the game')
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid move, try again')
main()
```

im able to get some items but not all

Comment: It looks like you left out some of the code necessary to reproduce

Comment: Please include the `get_item()` function, it looks like the problem comes from it.

Comment: i included the whole code i have now :)

Comment: i think i found the issue when ever i type in: if its a 2 name item 'radiant crest' it will give me a invalid entry but if i just type in the first word 'radiant' it  will add it the inventory. still not sure why it wont let me add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `.title()` on the player input, so each word is capitalized.

So the input

```
get glowing orb
```

becomes:

```
Get Glowing Orb
```

But the two-word items in the room dictionary aren't capitalized in the second word:

```
'item': 'Glowing orb'
```

And so the item name does not match.